# android studio fails to launch app with external libs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apache-commons, chilkat

I want to use ftp facilities in my android application, so I tried to add apache-commons-net:3.4 library.
Build is done successfully but it fails when I want to run or debug the application.
So I tried to use ivy-2-4-0 library and also Chilkat library, for all of them I get the same error.
Except for Chilkat for which it's a bit different, I only copied the library in my `libs` directory and declare the `file` dependency in `dependencies` tab of my project structure.

The displayed error is :

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:compileLint
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:checkReleaseManifest
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:prepareOrgOsmdroidOsmdroidAndroid501Library UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:prepareReleaseDependencies
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MapsForgeForOsmdroid:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:googleplayservices_lib:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:googleplayservices_lib:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:googleplayservices_lib:classes UP-TO-DATE
:googleplayservices_lib:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepare2ndGuideMapsForgeForOsmdroidUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgOsmdroidOsmdroidAndroid501Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOsmbonuspack_v55Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

What's wrong with my project?

regards,
Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","sources":[{}]}

You have too many methods. There can only be **65536 methods for dex**.

You can use the [**multidex support**](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html).

Just add these lines in the `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Also in your `Manifest` add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you are using a own `Application` class, change the parent class from `Application` to `MultiDexApplication`.